# grepl and group_by to summarise in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
region_calls = data.frame(
  samples = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S1", "S2", "S3"),
  CN_Region = c("A","A","A", "B", "B", "B"), 
  CN_State = c("0", "NoCall1or2", "1", "2", "NoCall1or2", "NoCall")
)
```

I tried to do this:

```
region_calls %>% group_by(CN_Region) %>%
  summarise(call_rate = sum(grepl("0|NoCall_1or2|1|NoCall_2or3|2|3|NoCall_3or4|4", CN_State)/n()),
            fixed_call_rate = sum(grepl("0|1|2|3|4", CN_State)/n()))
```

However each region is giving the same `call_rate` and `fixed_call_rate`

Expected answer is:

[image: Expected answer]

Basically, I am excluding `NoCall` (not `NoCall1or2`) from the numerator but not from the `n()` in the denominator

What am I missing? I also tried `nrow(.)` in the denominator. I saw some similar questions but they tackle `grepl` separately thanI intended to. Any cleaner `dplyr` approaches are also welcome.

Comment: FWIW `mean(grepl(.))` is the same as `sum(grepl(.))/n()`; also `0|1|2|3|4` as regex is usually written as `[0-4]`

Comment: Sorry, your example data doesn't work -- `CN_Region` and `CN_State` have 6 elements, but `samples` has 8

Comment: As near as I can tell your code works as intended, can you please (1) double check for typos (2) try and reproduce your issue on a fresh R session (3) update your question with a fully reproducible example [output that's wrong, and expected output]?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code to add the expected answer. Also in your first comment, `mean(grepl(.))` we are not passing any strings for it to search though? can you expand it?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of calculating `call_rate` and `fixed_call_rate` ? What you want to include in them and what you want to exclude?

Comment: strings passed to `grepl` state that. Basically for `call_rate` I want to add all values except for pure `NoCalls` to the numerator divided by nrows in that group (which will include the `NoCalls` row and for `fixed_call_rate` I just want the sum of integer `CN_State` values in the numerator divided by the same denominator as `call_rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `call_rate` we can calculate ratio of values where we don't have `"NoCall"`. We don't need regex for `call_rate` since it is an exact match and not a pattern match. For `fixed_call_rate` we use `grepl` to find ratio of values that have only numbers in them. We add word boundaries for it (`\\b`) so that it matches only `"1"`, `"2"` etc and not `"NoCall1or2"`

```
library(dplyr)

region_calls %>%
  group_by(CN_Region) %>%
  summarise(call_rate = mean(CN_State != "NoCall"),
            fixed_call_rate = mean(grepl('\\b\\d\\b', CN_State)))

#  CN_Region call_rate fixed_call_rate
#  <fct>         <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 A             1               0.667
#2 B             0.667           0.333
```

Comment: Much neater solution, thanks. Why wouldn't `mean(grepl('[0-4]'))` work?

Comment: It would work but then it would also match 41, 84 and other such numbers. You need to add word boundaries for that as well. This should work `fixed_call_rate = mean(grepl('\\b[0-4]\\b', CN_State)))`

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(region_calls)[, .( call_rate = mean(CN_State != "NoCall"),
        fixed_call_rate = mean(grepl('\\b\\d\\b', CN_State))), CN_Region]
```